# "this.props.history.push" not re-rendering the component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

On button click I need to navigate to a different page and re render the components. But over hear, the webpage URL is changing, but the component is not reloading automatically. I need to do the reload manually. How to implement the re render automatically **without** using "**Redirect**"

```
class Main extends Component{
       
     state={
       product:[]
     }
     
     componentDidMount(){
         const id=this.props.params.name;
         const check=data.filter(i=>i.id===id);
        if(check)
          return  this.setState({product:check[0]})
        return window.location="/"; 
    }

    handleClick=(item)=>{
       return this.props.history.push(`/products/${item}`);
    }

    render(){
    
     return (
       <button onClick={()=>handleClick("dell")}>Navigate</button>
      )

    }
}
```

Comment: please post working code https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-murdock-p84s1

Comment: its a really big code... so what I m doing here is when the component is mounted, i will check whether its present in my datas array, if its not present i will redirect to home. When i click the button inside the render method , i need to navigate to a different page, but its not re rendering

Comment: you are right. but above bit of the code is not a exact problem. please create some simple problem scenario then only we can find the problem on you code.